# How to update hook value from another widget - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hook, flutter-hooks

I'm facing an issue with a HookWidget and a StatelessWidget in a Flutter app. I'm passing values from both hooks to the stateless widget. The problem I'm encountering is that the value of `useTextEditingController` (`controller`) does not update as expected.

here is an example :

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CustomHookWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomHookWidget extends HookWidget {
  const CustomHookWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final controller = useTextEditingController();
    final customHook = useState(0);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: controller,
          ),
          TheStatelessWidget(
            hook: customHook,
            text: controller.text,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TheStatelessWidget extends HookWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<int> hook;
  final String text;

  const TheStatelessWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.hook,
    required this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (text.isEmpty) {
          print('empty');
          print(text);
        } else {
          hook.value += 1;
        }
      },
      child: Text('Change Value'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?  It is working for my case

Comment: I have edited the answers. actually the problem is with the textEditingController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial  `TextEditingController`'s text is empty, that's why you are getting empty string all the time. You can pass the controller instead to get updated value.

```dart
class CustomHookWidget extends HookWidget {
  const CustomHookWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = useTextEditingController();
    final customHook = useState(0);
  

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: controller,
          ),
          Text('Value: ${customHook.value}'),
          TheStatelessWidget(
            hook: customHook,
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TheStatelessWidget extends HookWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<int> hook;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  const TheStatelessWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.hook,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (controller.text.isEmpty) {
          print('empty');
          print(controller.text);
        } else {
          hook.value += 1;
        }
      },
      child: Text('Change Value'),
    );
  }
}
```